# Style of Popover from React-Bootstrap is not being applied to my component.

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, react-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I am trying to implement [Popover with overlay trigger](https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#popovers-overlay-trigger) in React - Bootstrap.

[It is supposed to look like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Avb8u.png)

I implemented it using this code:

```
var {Button, Overlay, OverlayTrigger, ButtonToolbar, Popover} = require('react-bootstrap');

...
<ButtonToolbar>
<OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="left" overlay={<Popover title="Popover left"><strong>Holy guacamole!</strong> Check this info.</Popover>}>
  <Button bsStyle="default">Holy guacamole!</Button>
</OverlayTrigger>
</ButtonToolbar>
```

I compared them using Inspect-Element. I noticed that none of the `.popover` styling is there for my implementation when I inspected element. Also, there is a `pseudo` `::after` element right after the `arrow` component in the original (the example in the react bootstrap website). That `::after` component is also missing in my implementation. I am not sure why the style is messed-up/overwritten. I'm including everything correctly I think, as per this line:

```
var {Button, Overlay, OverlayTrigger, ButtonToolbar, Popover} = require('react-bootstrap');
```

In the end, I cannot see the little arrow of the Popover in my implementation. Why is the `::after` disappearing? How can I make the little arrow (triangle css) visible in my implementation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The react bootstrap we use needs to be prefixed in-order to work properly. SO I needed to go into react-bootstrap and prefix `popover`, `arrow`, with `bt3-` prefix. Then all the styles got imported.

Comment: I am facing same issue. Could you please elaborate your answer, little more.

Comment: Sam here. @SutikshanDubey. Could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

in my case the problem was that i passed a wrapper component on the overlay prop of the OverlayTrigger , like this:

```
function Wrapper(){
     return <Popover 
              /*props...*/ 
     />
}
<OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="left" overlay={<Wrapper/>}>
     <Button bsStyle="default">Holy guacamole!</Button>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

instead of component like that:

```
const popover =<Popover 
              /*props...*/ 
     />
<OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="left" overlay={popover }>
     <Button bsStyle="default">Holy guacamole!</Button>
</OverlayTrigger>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add style in base.js , as popover is not in the body at render time it will up at runtime just like modal. so you need to modify popover class in your base.js style

```
.popover{background-color:aliceblue}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too also had this issue but could not follow the suggested answer. Instead I was able to find an example of the usage provided by the github website and this solved the problem for me:

Reference: https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components/overlays/#popovers

```
import Button from 'react-bootstrap/Button';
import OverlayTrigger from 'react-bootstrap/OverlayTrigger';
import Popover from 'react-bootstrap/Popover';

const popover = (
  <Popover id="popover-basic">
    <Popover.Header as="h3">Popover right</Popover.Header>
    <Popover.Body>
      And here's some <strong>amazing</strong> content. It's very engaging.
      right?
    </Popover.Body>
  </Popover>
);

const Example = () => (
  <OverlayTrigger trigger="click" placement="right" overlay={popover}>
    <Button variant="success">Click me to see</Button>
  </OverlayTrigger>
);

render(<Example />);
```

At first I was not using Popover.Header and such so that seemed to be my issue. Hope this can help others.